# how to search for a date in sqlite database using python?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, date, search

I have a database (called 'all_bookings')that has a column called 'date', in a table called 'bookings' which stores dates in the 'dd/mm/yyyy' form, for example '16/10/2017.' I want to write a function in python that will search for all dates on a particular month, and output them. For example, if in the dates stored where '12/12/2017', '23/11/2018',and  '19/12/2018', and I wanted to output all dates that are in December, how would I do this? I know how to search for a specific date, just not a particular month. Any help would be gladly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: have you tried this(making a query) yourself?

Comment: no, how do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SUBSTR function will do what you want. Modified to do what was asked in the OP's comment.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

events = [ 
    ('12/12/2017', 'ev_1'),
    ('23/11/2018', 'ev_2'),
    ('19/12/2018', 'ev_3'),
    ]

conn.execute('CREATE TABLE bookings (date, event)')
conn.executemany('INSERT INTO bookings (date, event) values (?,?)', events)

validMonth = False
while not validMonth:
    lookForMonth = input('What month, please? (number from 1 through 12):')
    try:
        validMonth = 1<=int(lookForMonth)<=12
    except:
        pass

sqlCmd = 'SELECT date FROM bookings WHERE SUBSTR(date,4,2)="%.2i"' % int(lookForMonth)
for row in conn.execute(sqlCmd):
    print (row)
```

Results are:

```
('12/12/2017',)
('19/12/2018',)
```

Comment: thanks, this works, how would i adjust it for instead of using the month searching for as '12', i want for search for a month that was inputted by the user, like a variable?